# Can I use non-renewing subscriptions for an app which offers a service, but has no free features?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit, non-renewing-subscription

I want to write an app, which enables the user to calculate financial credit plans. The users will be professionals in the financial sector. The idea is that they pay for each month of usage, basically a subscription. The app will not have any free features, so the subscription does not "unlock" premium features, instead the subscription "unlocks" all functionality of the app.
Can I use In-app non-renewable subscriptions for that? 
Can someone point me to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the non-renewing subscription option for your application.

Reference tutorial [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/36270/in-app-purchases-non-renewing-subscription-tutorial)

If you would not like to provide any functionality free then I will suggest to make your application as paid application. Otherwise maximum chances are there for your application to be rejected.

Comment: The wish of my customer is to charge a monthly fee for using his app. It is B2B app. So, the idea is not to give it out for free, and then charge for In-App purchases. His idea is that the user subscribes to his app from the beginning. Is that possible and how?

Comment: I think you need to provide access of your application at least once, Once 1 cycle of your calculation complete then you can ask user to do subscribe for the same.

Comment: I have implemented such thing in one of my previous application.. In that I have given 3 chances.. You can go with that if its fine with you..